# Generate an executable from object files in different formats

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, executable, bfd

Say that I have two files main.o compiled from gcc and another file function.o compiled from MSVC; 
is it possible to generate an executable (by linking) from these files?
Is this what BFS (binary file descriptor) library designed for?
I mean can I use BFS to do this?
If not, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to generate an executable (by linking) from these files?

Perhaps.

`C++` code produced by different compilers is not link compatible, but `C` code usually is (at least on UNIX). On Windows, it may or may not be possible. At a minimum, you should tell us which versions of `MSVC` and `gcc` you used to build the objects.

> Is this what BFS (binary file descriptor) library designed for?

You probably mean the `BFD` [library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library). No, that's not what it is for.